# Binding: Appending to href

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In my Angular 2 test app, I am trying to append an `id` the following as part of my HTML template:

```
<a href="https://www.domainname.com/?q="+{{text.id}}>URL</a>
```

Not this fails with an error:

> (Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element')

and I am not sure how to append `{{text.id}}` to this URL.

Do I need to do this in my component, or can it be done somehow inside the HTML template?

BTW, as one would expect, this works just fine (but that's not what I want to do, I need to append text.id to url):

```
<a href="https://www.domainname.com/?q=">{{text.id}}</a>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use either:

```html
<a href="https://www.domainname.com/?q={{text.id}}">URL</a>
```

or (from the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#bind-to-the-href-property)):

```html
<a [href]="'https://www.domainname.com/?q=' + text.id">URL</a>
```

---

Regarding the question, it's important to notice: 
The error message is misleading.

When you use `{{ expression }}`, angular will evaluate the `expression` and place its value right where the `{{}}` is. So you don't need to `+` the result of `{{}}` to the string as you do. In other words:

```html
<a href="something="+{{ expression }}> WRONG </a>

<a href="something={{ expression }}"> RIGHT </a>
<a [href]="'something=' + expression"> RIGHT </a>
```

Comment: what can i do if I want on an event (click) = "isCollapsed{{data_time}} = !isCollapsed{{data_time}}"

Comment: @JayMomaya In an event, you don't need to use `{{` or `}}`. Try: `(click)="isCollapsed(data_time)"`.

Answer (score 25):

Alternatively, you can use the following syntax:

```
[attr.href]="'https://www.domainname.com/?q=' + text.id"
```

---

This might be the preferred way when you want to bind to a variable like

```
url: string = 'https://www.domainname.com';
```

which would then be bound by

```
[attr.href]="url"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me (angular 8-7-6-5):

1. < a href="{{'mailto:' + data.emailId }}"> Send Mail < /a>
2. < a href="{{'tel:' + data.phoneNumber }}"> +911234567890 < /a>
3. < a href="{{'/' + data.redirectURL }}"> Open Google < /a>

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where it did not work for
`<a href="{{environment.urls.rclUrl}}">`
but `<a href="{{rclUrl}}">`
works along with defining
rclUrl = environment.urls.rclUrl in ts file